# Node application won't start in Docker if there's a shared volume

Tags: node.js, docker, gatsby

I generated a Gatsby website localy. Then I setup a Docker container to run it. It's a standard setup : copying `package.json`, installing the modules, copying the local files and starting the dev script with a shared volume.

But when it starts, I run into an error :

```
gatsby_1     |  ERROR
gatsby_1     |
gatsby_1     | There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed in your site's "node_modules" directory. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"? You might need to delete your "package-lock.json" as well.
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM node:14.11.0

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gatsby", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0"]
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - 8082:8080

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.5.1-php7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./wordpess/plugins:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
      - ./wordpess/themes:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes

  gatsby:
    build: ./gatsby
    ports: 
      - 8080:8000
    volumes:
      - ./gatsby:/app
```

But, if I remove the volume for the Gatsby container, everything rune well.

So my guess is there's something wrong with permissions somewhere, but I can't figure it out.

Here is a [repo with the whole project](https://github.com/Axiol/wordpress-gatsby).

Comment: Yes, the `volumes:` overwrite the contents of the `/app` directory with the content from your local filesystem, and basically everything your Dockerfile does is completely ignored.  You can safely delete that block to run the code that's actually built into the image.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the way. What about prodcution deployment where we just use the buit image and there's no code to share and no volume set in the `docker-compose.yml`? I'd have to use another `Dockerfile` juste for prod?